# Ilmerge for .NET 4.7 Compiling

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ilmerge

Is there any way to use ilmerge for .NET 4.7 because as i try to by ilmerge GUI the program tell me that the maximum .net is .net 4.5?  becouse i want to compile app.exe and DotNetZip.dll

Comment: It is a bug in the ILMerge GUI utility. If you use the command line tools, it should work. Also see this issue on GitHub : https://github.com/Microsoft/ILMerge/issues/15 .